# Finding out how long a customer has traded for

Tags: mysql, dax

I need to find out how long customers have been trading with the company. For that I guess I first need to find out when the first purchase took place for each customer and then calculate the difference between the first purchase and the current date (GETDATE( but am quite new to SQL and DAX power bi and really not sure how to go about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share sample data with expected output

Comment: Sorry @Amit. Didn't see your request. Besides, it was for an assignment. I just wasnt sure at all what function to use and was a quite lost with it. Between google and some extra help I managed though. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I needed it for an assignment and couldn't wait so I think I found it and wanted to share it if anybody finds it useful. The term for the length that a customer has been trading with a company is known as "tenure" actually which I didn't know.

This is what I've done using DAX. Am inexperienced so apologies if the explanation and terminology is not all correct, but the DAX measures are;

First do a measure to find the Min criteria of the customers order dates:

--- Cust. First Orders = MIN(FactInternetSales[OrderDate])

Then, do a second measure to find the Max criteria of the customers order date:

--- Cust. Last Orders = MAX(FactInternetSales[OrderDate])

And the final 3rd measure is to calculate the difference between first and last orders:

--- in years; Cust. Years Tenure = DATEDIFF([Cust. First Orders],[Cust. Last Orders],YEAR)

--- or in months; Cust. Months Tenure = DATEDIFF([Cust. First Orders],[Cust. Last Orders],MONTH)

It's not quite mine as I wouldn't have been able to do it by myself but hope its helpful. Thanks